# Why does the final energy of a body set moving on a rough surface depend only on the initial state?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction

I came across the following problem in a textbook:

> A hollow uniform sphere, initially only possessing rotational energy, is set upon a rough horizontal surface. Calculate the ratio of final to initial kinetic energy, given that the coefficient of kinetic friction as a function of x is given by $\mu = a(1+x)$.

[Here, final ke refers to the ke after the condition for pure rolling has been achieved.]

After solving this problem, I noticed that my answer did not depend upon the variation of friction coefficient, and managed to prove that this is indeed the case for any $\mu(x)$. Is there any deep reason behind this independence?

Comment: Isn't this the work-energy theorem in action with the sphere as the system and the frictional force as the external force. How the work is done does not matter what matters is the net amount of work done on the system.

Comment: @Farcher pure rolling does not begin when a certain fixed value of energy is lost, but when the ratio of the translational and rotational ke reaches a certain value(= mr^2/I).